# What does this type of function mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, syntax

In the below, I'm confused by the syntax

```
(function (h,j) { })
```

What does it mean in javascript to have a function sit inside ()'s like that?

```
function myfunc(c, b) {
    try {
            (function (h, j) {
                //do a bunch of stuff
            })
    } catch (e) {
        myerror(e)
    }
};
```

Comment: This piece of code doesn't appear to do anything. Are you sure this is all there is?

Comment: `(function (h,j) { })` doesn't do anything. `(function (h,j) { })(arg1,arg2)` creates and executes an anonymous function. Notice the difference is the parentheses after the first part - just like saying `alert` vs. `alert()`, one mentions a function, the other executes it.

Comment: You might want to check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539205/javascript-inline-function-vs-predefined-functions

Comment: I love this construct. It reminds me of a magic trick or a ninja flash-bomb-shuriken maneuver.

Comment: There is more, I just ripped it out of some code to do an example..but I think everyone here and below caught on to what I was saying....thx.

Comment: The link to the other stackoverflow article was good which led to this:

http://yura.thinkweb2.com/named-function-expressions/

which is very useful

Answer (score 15):

By itself, such a function declaration is useless. This kind of declaration is only useful if you actually invoke the function, which is done like this:

```
(function (h, j) { ... } (x, y));
```

This is usually done to hide variables, since JavaScript only has function scope (no block scope).

#### Edit:

Some examples - hopefully these don't confuse things...

As mentioned in a comment, this technique is useful for keeping variables out of the global scope. For example, some initialisation script might do the following:

```
(function () {
    var x = 42;
    var y = 'foo';

    function doInitialisation(a, b) {
        // ...
    }

    doInitialisation(x, y);
}());
```

None of `x`, `y` or `doInitialisation` are visible after the function completes.

Another use-case is for avoiding closures in loops. E.g. the following causes a well-known problem:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].onclick = function () {
        alert(i);
    };
}
```

In the above example, every onclick handler shares the same value of `i`. Function scope can avoid this:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].onclick = (function (x) {
        return function() {
            alert(x);
        }
    }(i));
}
```

Comment: To add to that: no other block enclosure syntax in Javascript actually limits scope. Variables declared in the body of anything other than a function usually get injected into the global namespace, which [can cause problems](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/).

Comment: I was looking at a script and pulled the code from that, I also saw this going on a lot:

(function (h, j) { //a bunch of foo })(function() { //more foo })

In this case I would assume that the second function actually is invocation of the first function passing it h and j?

Comment: That looks like the second function is passed as the argument to the first function... pretty confusing.

Answer (score 4):

`()` is a grouping operator, and it returns the result of evaluating the expression inside it.

So while

```
> function(x,y) {}
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
```

by itself is a `SyntaxError`, but by surrounding it in parentheses, the expression inside the parentheses is evaluated and returned.

```
> (function(x,y) {})
function (x,y) {}
```

Function expressions and declarations do not yield any value, so we get `undefined` as a result.

Function Declaration

```
> function a(x,y) {}
undefined
```

Function Declaration (with grouping operator)

```
(function a(x,y) {})
function a(x,y) {}
```

Function Expression

```
> var x = function(x,y) {}
undefined
```

Function Expression (with grouping operator)

```
> var x;
> (x = function(x,y) {})
function (x,y) {}
```

However, the usage in your example seems to be useless. It does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

That syntax is what is known as an [Anonymous Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function). Most often, you will see them used as callbacks for various other function calls (for example, in jQuery).

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't answer the question why this anonymous function is wrapped in parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

It's a kind of inline function, so you can take the advantages of covariance. By this I mean,inside

(function (h, j) {
            //do a bunch of stuff
        })
You can access the variables of the containing function , here it's `function myfunc(c, b) {}`