# create a function for action creator in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

this is my action, I straight away dispatch an object in getMsgList

```
export function getMsgList(){
    dispatch=>{
        axios.get('/user/getmsglist')
        .then(res=>{
            if(res.state===200 && res.data.code===0){
                dispatch({type:MSG_LIST, payload:res.data.data})
            }
        })
    }
}
```

but I've seen some people create a function instead, they'll do it like this.

```
...
dispatch(getMsg(res.data.data)
...

getMsg(msg){
    return{type:MSG_LIST,payload:msg}
}
```

What is the purpose of that 'extra function'?

Comment: I recommend you to read some posts on this blog. https://daveceddia.com/  This person is really good at explaning on things in React

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: Inline function vs predefined functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539205/javascript-inline-function-vs-predefined-functions)

Answer (score 0):

[Redux] (https://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Actions.html) explains this. This is called an Action Creator.

> In a real app, it is wiser to generate a unique ID every time something new is created. It's a good idea to pass as little data in each action as possible. For example, it's better to pass index than the whole todo object. **Action creators** are exactly that—functions that create actions.

Essentially it reduces copy and paste for the type string, save code, and clarify logic using an **Action Creator**