# Performance difference between function initialization locations [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, parsing, optimization, initialization

I am curious about the performance difference between initializing a function outside a loop vs inline:

Outside the loop:

```js
const reducer = (acc, val) => {
  // work
};

largeArray.reduce(reducer);
```

Inline:

```js
largeArray.reduce((acc, val) => {
  // work
});
```

I encounter this kind of situation regularly, and, unless I'm going to reuse the function, it seems useful to avoid introducing another variable into my scope by using the inline version.

**Is there a performance difference in these two examples or does the JS engine optimize them identically?**

For example: is the inline function being created every time the loop runs and then garbage collected? And if so:

- What kind of effect does this have on performance, and
- Does the size of the function affect this? For example, a function that is 200 vs 30_000 unicode characters.

Are there any other differences or things I'm not considering?

Hopefully you understand my train of thought and can provide some insight about this. I realize that I can read all of the docs and source code for V8 or other engines, and I would get my answer, but that seems like an overwhelming task to understand this concept.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: inline functions vs predefined functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539205/javascript-inline-functions-vs-predefined-functions)

Answer (score 0):

I did run test on jsben

SET1(random used twice): http://jsben.ch/8Dukx

SET2:(used once): http://jsben.ch/SnvxV

Setup

```
const arr = [ ...Array(100).keys() ];
const reducer = (acc, cur) => (acc + cur);
```

Test 1

```
let sumInline = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => (acc + cur), 0);
let sumInlineHalf = arr.slice(0, 50).reduce((acc, cur) => (acc + cur), 0);

console.log(sumInline, sumInlineHalf);
```

Test 2

```
let sumOutline = arr.reduce(reducer, 0);
let sumOutlineHalf = arr.slice(0, 50).reduce(reducer, 0);

console.log(sumOutline, sumOutlineHalf);
```

Be surprised

Answer (score 0):

> What kind of effect does this have on performance, and

None.

> Does the size of the function affect this? For example, a function that is 200 vs 30_000 unicode characters.

Functions aren't executed as "unicode characters". It doesn't matter how "long" the code is.

> Are there any other differences or things I'm not considering?

A very important one: Code is written for *humans*, not computers. And [why do you even ask me?](https://www.google.com/amp/s/ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/amp/)

> is the inline function being created every time the loop runs and then garbage collected?

That would be unneccessary and slow. So probably: no.

Comment: Any links to documentation sources for your response?